# Strip " from outside $var

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

$varHi I know this is an extremely basic task, but I am some what confused.

I am pulling a String back from a Database and assigning it to `$var`. I am then outputting this value into a text area. However, when I do, the string is surrounded in " ".

e.g. "This is the String", but I just want : This is the String

I have tried many functions. I am using chr(34) to search for the ", but to no avail. It will only replace them if it is inside the string. Not on the outside / surrounding the string.

```
$var = str_replace( chr(34), "" ,$var);
```

Thanks In Advance for any help.

EDIT : Turn's out I was outputting incorrectly into the text area 
    ""
should have been

Thank's for the help.

Comment: are you sure the " are part of the variable or is it part of the surrounding html? could you post the html snippet please?

Comment: pls accept my answer, helps me get some points, and also increases your chances of getting an answer in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$var = str_replace( '"', '' ,$var);`

See it in action [here](http://codepad.org/XtmFhVpn)

Comment: You'll need to escape that double-quote, or wrap it in single-quotes.

Comment: HI that did not work for me. The example link does not use a $var in the function. It uses "hi" typed in. Would this be effecting it?

Comment: `'"hi"'` is just an example :) http://codepad.org/7VRKhNiy ...it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = str_replace('"', '', $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `$var = str_replace('"', '', $var);`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace), as already mentioned but that would remove quotes from the string body also (if you have any)

to remove only the first and last ones you could use the [trim](http://php.net/trim) function with the optional second parameter

edit: and if you have quotes inside the string that you want to keep those might be escaped so you might use str_replace to use only the quotes instead the escaped quotes ( **str_replace('\"', '"', $string)** );

Answer (score 0):

The double speech should only appear if they are in your data being pulled, unless you are echoing or printing to the text area incorectly.

As said above the

```
$var = str_replace('"', '', $var);
```

Will work fine, but its a bit of a hack if your data doesn't have the double speech in it to start with.